# No connection between Ubuntu 18.04 and Arduino

Tags: arduino

There's no connection between Arduino and my computer.
When I upload a program, I get the error message:

```
avrdude: ser_open(): can't open device "/dev/ttyS0": Permission denied
An error occurred while uploading the sketch
```

Anybody knows the problem and the solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your user currently doesn't have permissions to access the device. To gain those permissions, simply add your user to the `dialout` group (replace userName with your user name):

```
sudo usermod -a -G dialout userName
```

You need to log out and back in for the changes to take effect.